# Tkinter Entry - Error message when entering new value while field is empty

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, a variable is assigned a tkinter-variable that is then traced:

```
self.tklon = tk.DoubleVar()
self.tklon.trace('w', self.trace_callback)
```

In the GUI, I have an Entry-widget to hold this variable:

```
self.lonEntry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable = self.tklon)
```

In general, everything works. But when I delete the content of the Entry to input a new value, the Entry is empty for a brief moment. It still triggers the trace and as a result, I get the following error message:

```
File "xxxx", line 529, in get
    return self._tk.getdouble(self._tk.globalgetvar(self._name))
    _tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got ""
```

and the line that throws the error message in the trace_callback() function is:

```
self.lon = self.tklon.get()
```

It doesn't do any further harm in my case, but the continuous error messages in the terminal are annoying.

I was thinking that there might be a solution by

a) Setting a default value to the Entry when it is empty

b) Only update the textvariable assigned to the Entry when you hit Enter on the keyboard

but I don't see any such options to the Entry-widget. I can't think of any validity check since there is nothing more primitive than .get(), which throws the error...

Did I just miss the right information? Is there another workaround? Is there perhaps even no solution to this?

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: What does the definition of `trace_callback` look like? Can you alter it so it returns without doing anything if the entry is empty?

Comment: use ``.bind('<Return>', func)`` to do stuff when enter is pressed. ``func`` will be passed an event, so make sure you have the parameter

Comment: We need to see what trace_callback is doing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use `bind`, I will try that. To answer the other question: The respective line in `trace_callback` that triggers the error is `self.lon = self.tklon.get()`.

Comment: `get()` by itself should not cause the error. It must be what you are doing with the value once you `get()` it. Based on the error it appears that you are grabbing an empty string and then either trying to apply it to the `tk.DubleVar()` or attempting to do some other math that is expecting a double and just getting an empty string instead. It may also be that the actual double object is throwing the error when you try to get its value.

Comment: Well the traceback in the console says specifically it is the `get()`. I can also confirm this by placing some `print()` around it, it is where the code stops.

Comment: using `bind()` works! But only as a **replacement** to trace, since it is executed independently it seems.

Comment: @JohannesHinrichs I have added an answer that lets you keep the use of trace and fixes your error issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be how the nature of `textvariable` works in tkinter.
So when the value changes in the entry field it applies whatever that value is to the variable in question. Here it is a double. The problem is encountered when a value that is not a double compatible string is applied to that variable.

When you use `get()` in `DoubleVar()` what happens is the actually double var attempts to return a double. However an empty string cannot convert to a double so it errors out.

One easy way to deal with this is to handle the error with a `try/except` statement.

Try this idea:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
tklon = tk.DoubleVar()

def trace_callback(*args):
    try:
        print(tklon.get())
    except:
        print("value not a valid double")


lonEntry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tklon).pack()
tklon.trace('w', trace_callback)
root.mainloop()
```

Alternativly and probably a better option you could change your `DoubleVar()` to `StringVar()` and test if the string is a double or not.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
tklon = tk.StringVar()
tklon.set(0.0)


def trace_callback(*args):
    if tklon.get().isdecimal():
        print("Do stuff with decimal")
    else:
        print("Value is not a decimal")


lonEntry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=tklon).pack()
tklon.trace('w', trace_callback)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes that looks like a valid approach, thanks! I will give it a try as well and see what is best in my case.